How can I auto scale fonts imported from mathabx?
Recently I asked this question and with the help of some comments, I was able to somehow find an answer. But as you can see in my answer, I could not make the summation symbol automatically scale based on whether it's inline or display style (so it can be considered a MWE). I would like to know the general mechanism of how I could import specific symbols from another font this way and scale them automatically (or even declare delimiters).
Update: Found the issue. I had \usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern} loaded when I was using xelatex or lualatex. This was changing the scaling for some reason. After removing it, I saw the intended result.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\div\relax
\let\circ\relax
\let\owns\relax
\let\convolution\relax
\let\diamond\relax
\let\bullet\relax
\let\ocirc\relax
\let\widecheck\relax
\let\emptyset\relax

\usepackage{mathabx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
    <-5.5> mathx5 <5.5-6.5> mathx6 <6.5-7.5> mathx7 <7.5-8.5> mathx8
    <8.5-9.5> mathx9 <9.5-10.5> mathx10 <10.5-11.5> mathx11
    <11.5-12.5> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\prodop} {\mathop}{mathx}{'271}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathxintop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'273}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}


\begin{document}
    $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$
    \[
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} i
    \]
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}

This MWE generates correct output. 
In my project, I see a weird behavior. I get correct output when I use pdflatex.
But when I use lualatex, I get wrong output with both symbols scaled the same.
I hope it's visible that the outputs are different for different compilers. See that in lualatex output, the int symbol is correct and smaller than the other two symbols.
Note: the MWE generates correct output for both pdflatex and lualatex. So it's something that's being done in my project separately I think.

I can't reproduce what you report when I turn your code into a minimal document I can compile. see below. please always post usable code which enables people to reproduce the problem you want help with.

@cfr I have updated the question with my latest findings. I wasn't sure if I should update the title but the updated MWE and the issue in my bigger project is described properly now I think. Please let me know if you have any idea why this could happen.

@cfr Thank you for your help. I was able to pinpoint the issue and now the output is correct for lualatex as well.

You've not provided usable code, but when I take the relevant bits of your snippets and make them compilable, I cannot reproduce the issue you report.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathxsumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}
\renewcommand*{\sum}{\DOTSI\mathop{\mathchoice{\mathxsumop}{\sumop}{\sumop}
{\sumop}}\ilimits@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$
\[
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} i
\]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}


That said, the fonts you are using provide optical sizing, so you should probably rather use something like
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathx5 <5.5-6.5> mathx6 <6.5-7.5> mathx7 <7.5-8.5> mathx8
  <8.5-9.5> mathx9 <9.5-10.5> mathx10 <10.5-11.5> mathx11
  <11.5-12.5> mathx12
}{}

which will use mathx12 rather than mathx10 if, say, your document uses 12pt rather than 10pt.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathx5 <5.5-6.5> mathx6 <6.5-7.5> mathx7 <7.5-8.5> mathx8
  <8.5-9.5> mathx9 <9.5-10.5> mathx10 <10.5-11.5> mathx11
  <11.5-12.5> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathxsumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}
\renewcommand*{\sum}{\DOTSI\mathop{\mathchoice{\mathxsumop}{\sumop}{\sumop}
{\sumop}}\ilimits@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$
\[
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} i
\]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}

Again, this all seems to work fine for me.

You are right, in a separate MWE, I also got the correct result but with the same commands in my project, I get different results. I have edited the post with MWE and shared the differences.

It seems the original issue is in your output too, the sum symbols both inline and in display styles have the same size rather than being scaled accordingly, right? Or am I seeing it incorrect

@Masum but that is what you have told latex to do, isn't it? you've told it to use the same symbol in each case. \sum isn't extensible the way \int is. latex would take the larger from largesymbols, I think, rather than symbols. but there is no equivalent as far as I can tell for mathx.

@Masum when you say the 'original issue is in your output', I don't follow. your original issue was about the symbol being taken from cm/lm and that is clearly not the case in my output. if you want to ask about size, I suggest you ask a new question about that.

I see, thank you for explaining, I did not know the two don't behave similarly in this regard. Sorry for being confusing, the original issue was about the scaling. My fault for not properly organizing the question. Could I ask how I can tell latex to use the smaller sum when it's inline? I think it will have something to do with mathchoice where I should use that symbol but I am not entirely sure about the syntax.

@Masum actually, they both come from the largesymbols font in cm, but the point is, they are separate characters in the default setup. so see if there is only one or two or whatever. if not, you would need to scale it. as I understood you question, it was about getting cm/lm rather than mathx. your code redefined \int twice rather than \int and \sum, which might be why.

I think it's due to LuaLaTeX, when I changed to pdflatex, the output I get seems correct. But when I change to Lualatex, first I get errors saying it cannot load mathx at 7pt, and if I fix it to 12pt, then the output becomes same as yours, both at same scale. I will update the question with this though I am not sure if this will be solvable.
